KVM: Recover console of VM which connected to console of another VM
How do I recover the console of the first guest when itself is connected to a guest of which it is the host?
Host1:~$ virsh console Guest1

...

Connected to domain 'Guest1'
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ])

Guest2 login: 


Guest1 has been connected to Guest2 using the virsh console Guest2 command.
Guest2 runs on Guest1 with the same KVM and LIBVIRT packages as Guest1 does on Host1.
I do not want to reboot any machine.
I possess the credentials of all machines.

Reading the documentation for virsh (see man virsh) we find,

-e, --escape string Set alternative escape sequence for console command. By default, telnet's ^] is used. Allowed characters when using hat notation are: alphabetic character, @, [, ], ^, _.

Using this information you can use ^] to disconnect from the first session, change the escape character to something like ^a, reconnect, and then use ^] as a pass-through this time to disconnect the second session:
virsh -e '^a' console guest1


Thank your for the explanation including a source and examples.

@viator I figure that if I give a reference then it helps people understand how I arrived at my answer. Otherwise it's just "I said so..."
